# kubernetes set-based label selector

Tags: kubernetes

I want to filter pods using set-based selector

given following pods

```
+ kubectl get pods --show-labels
NAME                                            READY   STATUS    RESTARTS        AGE     LABELS
csi-cephfsplugin-dk7g6                          3/3     Running   0               7d12h   app=csi-cephfsplugin,controller-revision-hash=758476fc67,pod-template-generation=12
csi-cephfsplugin-jlcpv                          3/3     Running   0               7d12h   app=csi-cephfsplugin,controller-revision-hash=758476fc67,pod-template-generation=12
csi-cephfsplugin-ll85n                          3/3     Running   0               7d12h   app=csi-cephfsplugin,controller-revision-hash=758476fc67,pod-template-generation=12
csi-cephfsplugin-pbf5n                          3/3     Running   0               7d12h   app=csi-cephfsplugin,controller-revision-hash=758476fc67,pod-template-generation=12
csi-cephfsplugin-provisioner-6f7ffd894d-9jt8c   6/6     Running   0               7d12h   app=csi-cephfsplugin-provisioner,pod-template-hash=6f7ffd894d
csi-cephfsplugin-provisioner-6f7ffd894d-q74x2   6/6     Running   0               7d12h   app=csi-cephfsplugin-provisioner,pod-template-hash=6f7ffd894d
csi-cephfsplugin-provisioner-6f7ffd894d-vn8m7   6/6     Running   0               7d12h   app=csi-cephfsplugin-provisioner,pod-template-hash=6f7ffd894d
csi-cephfsplugin-sqkz6                          3/3     Running   0               7d12h   app=csi-cephfsplugin,controller-revision-hash=758476fc67,pod-template-generation=12
csi-rbdplugin-2qf4v                             3/3     Running   0               7d12h   app=csi-rbdplugin,controller-revision-hash=79c748c46c,pod-template-generation=12
csi-rbdplugin-5f8ng                             3/3     Running   0               7d12h   app=csi-rbdplugin,controller-revision-hash=79c748c46c,pod-template-generation=12
csi-rbdplugin-6b9l2                             3/3     Running   0               7d12h   app=csi-rbdplugin,controller-revision-hash=79c748c46c,pod-template-generation=12
csi-rbdplugin-6whd8                             3/3     Running   0               7d12h   app=csi-rbdplugin,controller-revision-hash=79c748c46c,pod-template-generation=12
csi-rbdplugin-p67v7                             3/3     Running   0               7d12h   app=csi-rbdplugin,controller-revision-hash=79c748c46c,pod-template-generation=12
csi-rbdplugin-provisioner-7dffff7f4d-47bsb      7/7     Running   0               7d12h   app=csi-rbdplugin-provisioner,pod-template-hash=7dffff7f4d
csi-rbdplugin-provisioner-7dffff7f4d-mdzfv      7/7     Running   0               7d12h   app=csi-rbdplugin-provisioner,pod-template-hash=7dffff7f4d
csi-rbdplugin-provisioner-7dffff7f4d-zh76c      7/7     Running   0               7d12h   app=csi-rbdplugin-provisioner,pod-template-hash=7dffff7f4d

< many other pods >
```

I want to filter pods with label contain keyword csi,

```
kubectl get pods -l 'app in (csi)'
```

but get error

```
error: name cannot be provided when a selector is specified
```

Any idea ?

Answer (score 1):

You can use awk to regex match the pod name.

```
kubectl get pods --no-headers --show-labels | awk '{if ($NF ~ ".*app=csi.*") print $0}'
```

**$NF** is a variable representing the last column in a file/stream.

Comment: Thanks for help,  I found where the issue is ,  in my .bashrc  I have kubectl function that take any argument $@ but is missing a quote around $@.   


function kubectl() { echo "+ kubectl $@">&2; command kubectl $@; }

After fixing the quote issue  , I can use set-based selector to filter pods